# Put refresh control of table at the bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm going to implement a `UITableView` to show older items by pulling to the bottom of table, how can I show refresh icon `UIActivityIndicator` at the bottom of current list?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use open source library [SVPullToRefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) which has a simple to use method:

```
[tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    // append data to data source, insert new cells at the end of table view
    // call [tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating] when done
}];
```

When `actionHandler` block called, put your code to get older content.

Comment: It means that There is no way to act like instagram without components?

Comment: Ok, I got it, you want infinite scrolling which triggers an event to load older content. I've updated my answer.